# Add group and sub group in one group in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have 2 fields Cluster and saales organization.

like

```
Cluster      Sales organization  
_______      ___________________  
CL1          ORG1
CL1          ORG2
CL2          ORG3
CL2          ORG4
```

I need to create a formula to display the values in  following way

```
ORG1
ORG2
CL1
ORG3
ORG4
CL2
```

Can any one help me to produce this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create groups and specify field from datasource (CL1,CL2 containing as value).
Then simply place the field which has ORG type value just beneath this group.
And grouping will be done automatically.